# "alternative method" type questions

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have a numerical type question on matrices, for which I already have a solution, but is a bit tedious. I actually wanted to know an alternative method or wether that question is kind of a “standard result” question which I should learn. (For Example as $AX= \lambda X$) type questions are actually related to eigenvalues).

How should I be framing such a question on MSE. (I would of course want to see their approach as well not only the topic.)

Comment: Part of stating the problem clearly is telling your Readers whether the "alternative method" is intended for manual calculation or machine calculation.  What is "a bit tedious" for humans might be expeditious for a computer program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Clearly state the original question.
2. Show your own solution.
3. Explain that you are looking for an alternate solution. Be specific about what you are looking for. Something like "I want a solution that does not use complex numbers" or "I want a solution using the snake lemma".